# Eclipse auto-complete arguments type emphasis

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, eclipse-kepler

I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate question, but honestly I don't know how the feature is called. When I search in Eclipse Java auto-complete related questions I can't find it.

When I write **Java** code and use auto-complete and decide to accept with <kbd>Enter</kbd> one of given auto-complete options it will write the method for me, it will populate argument names and a small window will open where I will see in bold on which argument I'm currently on with cursor and what type it is. This **bold** argument updates in the popup and always puts emphasis on the current argument as I'm writing the arguments.

[image: Screenshot to clarify]

1. What is the name of this feature?
2. Is there a way to tweak it? Is there **Eclipse Kepler** compatible plugin or some setting/workaround or shortcut to get it to show again? Or preferably display it all the time? The only way for me to get the window/pop-up re-displayed is to go to the open bracket of that method and press
   <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and choose the first option with <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then the window/popup will show. And it's very long-winded for me. I think a long time ago **Zend Studio 5.5** had this feature much more convenient and showing up constantly and I miss it a lot.

Comment: BTW: You can use Code Recommender plugin to customize the recommended choices. If you hover with Eclipse over a method it will show you a javadoc preview of the signature. Thats independend of the auto-complete. If you want to see it always, you can activate the Javadoc view (and click on the method).

Comment: Thanks but I have the javadoc over hover already, but this is not javadoc. Java doc will no emphasize argument in signature on current argument. So when I use cursor key and I'm over next argument the display box will change to emphasize then next argument.

Comment: Bit of off-topic note, in inteliJ it has Ctrl+P shortcut and you don't need to go to brackets or commons, it works everywhere on whole length of the method. And if that method has a parameter which is method it can display theirs arguments as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope that is what you are looking for:

In your Eclipse menu, go to Window->Preferences->Java->Editor

There you will find things like:

- Content Assist/Advanced + Favorites
- Templates

Hopefully, one of those is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will have much better sleep now :) 
The templates do not have directly nothing to do with this feature. 
But when I added key shortcuts for the **Java Proposals** or **Java Proposals (Task-Focused)** then I was able to get that window to pop up. I selected the key-bind to **Shift+Ctrl+Space** so it's very similar to auto complete. Then going into any method and pressing it on **open bracket** or **commas** will trigger the menu directly. This is many times better than my previous workflow.

Comment: If you want to disable filling the arguments altogether, it's inside `Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Content Assist`, under the name `Fill method arguments and show guessed arguments`.